# Laravel + Vue: Bundle size is too large but can't tell why

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I am using Vue for a small part of a laravel app.  I'm not using it for images so it's just the js and css inside of the Vue components.  It's 256kb and even after minifying it, it's somehow 256kb as well.  I just posted my package.json file below.  Is there any package that looks like a duplicate?  Or any other ways to reduce the bundle size?

````
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development  webpack --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development  webpack --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development  webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production  webpack --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.14",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.17.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0"
  }
}```
````

Comment: You can use a webpack bundle analyzer to get details about what is compiled in your bundle, ex https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Comment: Btw loadash can have a pretty big impact on the size depending on the way it's used